# nth_element on a vector of structs c++

Tags: c++, algorithm

I want to run the c++ function nth_element on a vector of structs but I'm not sure how to get it to work.

Here is my current code:

```
struct Point {
    int x, y, color;
};

bool compareByY (const Point &a, const Point &b)
{
    return a.y < b.y;
}

nth_element(points.begin(), points.size() +  points.size()/2, points.end(), compareByY);
```

Comment: What went wrong?  What output do you expect?

Comment: Please read,http://www.cplusplus.com/reference/algorithm/nth_element/?kw=nth_element

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I suppose that that call to `nth_element` produced a compile error, possibly one of those famously incomprehensible C++ template errors. But there should have been some sort of clue at least.

The second argument -- `points.size() +  points.size()/2` -- is not an iterator into the container; it's an integer. You meant `points.begin() + points.size()/2`.

Answer (score 2):

The arithmetic operation `points.size() + points.size()/2` doesn't give you an iterator, it gives you a `size_t`. `nth_element` needs an iterator as the second parameter.

I'm guessing it was just a typo with `size` vs `begin`. Here's the fix:

```
points.begin() + points.size()/2
```

Comment: This is wrong: the third argument to nth_element is an iterator to one-past-the-end, just as is provided.